# install binary shared object using autotools

Tags: autotools

How can I install a closed source, third party binary blob, (`libevilcompany.so`) into standard library locations (normally `/usr/lib` and possibly to be overwritten with `./configure --prefix=/tmp`), like as it was compiled from source code?

I'm using autotools.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a custom install rule by [extending the installation process](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Extending-Installation). For example, something like this in your Makefile.am:

```
install-exec-local:
    $(MKDIR_P) $(DESTDIR)$(libdir) && cp -a libevilcompany.so $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)
```

Comment: I'd just add - it might be better to use the `install-sh` script at the top level, i.e., `$(top_srcdir)`, which is a more portable solution. Also look at [`AC_PROG_INSTALL`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Particular-Programs.html), and the `INSTALL_PROGRAM` variable.

Comment: Instead of cp? Then you have to start faffing with --mode so as not to add +x bit, and install doesn't even create the dir structure for you. "left as an exercise for the reader" springs to mind here :-)

Comment: nevertheless, `install-sh` is there for a reason, and if you look at it, you'll find it has `-m <mode>`, and other options that *all* other `Makefile` targets generated by automake, etc., use. Even [`MKDIR_P`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Particular-Programs) evaluates to `install-sh [-c] -d` in most cases.